# SQL Delete from a subquery that uses Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I have to use sub query to select the rows I want to delete

```
DELETE FROM myTable 
WHERE
(
SELECT 
myFunction(table1.prikey, table2.bbbb) AS myValue,
timezoneFunction(table1.time, table3.ttt) AS recordTime
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.xxx = table2.xxxx
JOIN table3 ON table3.yyy = table1.yyy
WHERE table1.time DATEADD(day, -2 , Date1) AND DATEADD(day, 2 , Date12)
) myTable
WHERE 
recordTime BETWEEN Date1 AND Date12
AND myValue Between 10 AND 20
```

Putting the two functions on the where clause has great impact on the performance. So I have to do it the above way.

But now I get this error and it make complete sense. But What is the way around?

> View or function 'myTable' is not updatable because the modification
>   affects multiple base tables.

Comment: You will need to execute delete commands against the tables directly, Your functions has multiple underlying tables therefore you cannot do insert, update or delete operations against these functions, same is true for views.

Comment: As a side note, you don't want to be using `BETWEEN` [with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (especially on SQL Server).  Your statement also has a syntax error in it; what's the comparison supposed to be for `table1.time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are obvious typos in the code snippet.

Second, M Ali is right about having one table to delete from, but a DELETE FROM FROM clause with a CTE can be used.

Here is some sample code.  You join conditions may vary.  Please use > < when dealing with dates instead of between.

```
--
-- Sample code
--
;
WITH CTE_DELETE_LIST
AS
(
    SELECT 
        t1.priKey
        myFunction(t1.prikey, t2.bbbb) as myValue,
        timezoneFunction(t1.time, t3.ttt) as recordTime
    FROM table1 as t1
    JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.xxx = t2.xxx
    JOIN table3 as t3 ON t3.yyy = t1.yyy
    WHERE 
        t1.time > DATEADD(day, -2 , Date1) AND 
        t1.time < DATEADD(day, 2 , Date12)
) 
DELETE 
FROM M1
FROM MY_TABLE as M1 
JOIN CTE_DELETE_LIST as L1 ON M1.priKey = L1.priKey
WHERE 
    L1.recordTime > DATEADD(day, -2 , Date1) AND 
    L1.recordTime < DATEADD(day, 2 , Date12) AND
    L1.myValue > 10 AND 
    L1.myValue < 20
```

Comment: I think the answer to my question is using the second join. But why not using BETWEEN for dates?

Comment: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-best-practices-part-2  See date / time best practices in this article.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
DELETE FROM table_to_delete_from
FROM
(
SELECT 
table1.key1
,table1.key2
,myFunction(table1.prikey, table2.bbbb) AS myValue,
,timezoneFunction(table1.time, table3.ttt) AS recordTime
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.key1 = table2.key1
JOIN table3 ON table3.key2 = table1.key2
WHERE table1.time DATEADD(day, -2 , Date1) AND DATEADD(day, 2 , Date12)
) myTable

INNER JOIN
    table_1 table_to_delete_from
      ON table_to_delete_from.key_x = table_1.key_x

WHERE 
recordTime BETWEEN Date1 AND Date12
AND myValue Between 10 AND 20
```

Hope this will Help you,
Tell if it works for you :)
Good Luck !!!

Comment: There are clear syntax errors here.  See the Where clause missing a between key word.  See this blog about date ranges.  Should use > or <.  https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Comment: Hi crafty dba, I tried not to modify the filters and the joins the only thing i modified is the correct unsing of the delete statement :)

Comment: This is an obvious syntax error.  WHERE table1.time DATEADD(day, -2 , Date1) AND DATEADD(day, 2 , Date12).  It is missing the BETWEEN key word.

Comment: I agree CRAFTY DBA :)